# Issue sorting order of tableview data by date | Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift

Essentially I have a tableview populated using JSON data, the tableview contains sections that groups the data using `allowdate` from the JSON.

`allowdate` as seen below is contains a date but is not formatted numerically instead looks like: `March 26th 2020` so it makes difficult to control the order it is displayed in the tableview.

**In the function `fetchJSON` I do:**

```
self.structure.sort { $1. allowdate < $0.allowdate }
```

But this does not work correctly, and fails to put a date for example in January above one in March.

```
var sections = [TableSection]()
var structure = [TableStructure]()

private func fetchJSON() {

guard let url = URL(string: "\(URL.url)example"),
    let value = name.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryValueAllowed)
    else { return }

var request = URLRequest(url: url)
request.httpMethod = "POST"
request.httpBody = "item1=\(value)&item2=\(value)".data(using: .utf8)

URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, _, error in
    guard let data = data else { return }



    do {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
        self.structure.sort { $1. allowdate < $0.allowdate }
        let res = try decoder.decode([TableStructure].self, from: data)
        let grouped = Dictionary(grouping: res, by: { $0. allowdate })
        let keys = grouped.keys.sorted()
        self.sections = keys.map({TableSection(date: $0, items: grouped[$0]!)})
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }

    }

    catch {
        print(error)
    }
    }.resume()

}
```

**JSON:**

```
[
    {
        "person": "Jack",
        "allowdate": "March 26th 2020",
        "ready_time": "10:00 am"
    }
]
```

**To decode this JSON I am using the following structure:**

```
struct TableSections {
    let date : String
    var items : [TableStructure]
}


struct TableStructure: Decodable {

    let person: String
    let allowdate: String
    let ready_time: String

    enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case person, allowdate, ready_time

  }

}
```

Comment: You need to use a `DateFormatter` to convert `allowDate` to a `Date`. Then you can sort it easily.

Comment: Can you please show how I can take the date in the format it is now and format it? This is a bit foreign to me, I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Check this URL:

- https://nsdateformatter.com

It will help you you to try different `DateFormatter`.

Now for your scenario, Try changing the struct like this:

```
struct TableStructure: Decodable {
    let person: String
    let allowdate: Date?
    let ready_time: String

    enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case person, allowdate, ready_time
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

        self.person = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .person)
        self.ready_time = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .ready_time)

        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMMM d'th',yyyy"

        let allowDateStringValue = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .allowdate)
        self.allowdate = dateFormatter.date(from: allowDateStringValue)
    }

}
```

and you can sort the array as:

```
structure.sort { (firstStructure, secondStructure) -> Bool in
    if let firstDate = firstStructure.allowDate, let secondDate = secondStructure.allowDate {
        return firstDate.timeIntervalSince1970 < secondDate.timeIntervalSince1970
    }
    return false
}
```

If you don't want to change your `struct` format then you can go like this:

```
struct TableStructure: Decodable {
    let person: String
    let allowdate: String
    let ready_time: String

    enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case person, allowdate, ready_time
    }
}
```

and while sorting :

```
var dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMMM d'th',yyyy"

structure.sort { (firstStructure, secondStructure) -> Bool in
    if let firstDate = dateFormatter.date(from: firstStructure.allowDate),
        let secondDate = dateFormatter.date(from: secondStructure.allowDate) {
        return firstDate.timeIntervalSince1970 < secondDate.timeIntervalSince1970
    }
    return false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this in a playground.  It seems to work with different ordinals:

```
import UIKit

let json = """
[
    {
        "person": "Jack",
        "allowdate": "March 26th 2020",
        "ready_time": "10:00 am"
    },
    {
        "person": "Jill",
        "allowdate": "January 1st 2020",
        "ready_time": "1:00 pm"
    },
    {
        "person": "Don",
        "allowdate": "January 10th 2020",
        "ready_time": "1:25 pm"
    }
]
"""

struct TableStructure: Decodable {
    // These first three come frm the json
    let person: String
    let allowdate: String
    let readyTime: String
    // We'll calculate this one later
    let compareDate: Date

    // This date formatter will read in dates like "January 10th 2020"
    // So to use this, we will need to pull the ordinal letters off first
    static let dateFormatter: DateFormatter = {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMM dd yyyy"
        return dateFormatter
    }()

    enum DecodeError: Error {
        case compareDateError
    }

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case person
        case allowdate
        case readyTime
    }

    // We decode the three key/values that are passed down, and we calculate a date that we can use to compare
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        person = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .person)
        readyTime = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .readyTime)
        allowdate = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .allowdate)

        if let date = TableStructure.comparingDate(from: allowdate) {
            compareDate = date
        } else {
            throw DecodeError.compareDateError
        }

    }

    // We pull the ordinal letters off of the date, and are left with something cleaner
    // A regex could make this much simpler, but me and regex's, we don't get along so great
    static func comparingDate(from dateString: String) -> Date? {
        var datePurgedArray = dateString.split(separator: " ")
        if datePurgedArray.count == 3 {
            datePurgedArray[1] = datePurgedArray[1].filter("0123456789.".contains)
            let newDateString = datePurgedArray.joined(separator:" ")
            print(newDateString)
            return TableStructure.dateFormatter.date(from: newDateString)
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }

}

if let jsonData = json.data(using: .utf8) {
    print("json Data is \(jsonData)")
    do {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
        let array = try decoder.decode([TableStructure].self, from: jsonData).sorted { $0.compareDate < $1.compareDate }

        print("array is \(array)")
    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription + "could not decode array")
    }
} else {
    print("could not get data from json")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The string date format cannot be sorted reliably.

You have to decode the date string as `Date`. That's what the date decoding strategies are designed for.

There is one problem: `DateFormatter` doesn't support literal ordinal date strings like `1st`, you have to remove `st`, `nd`, `rd`, `th`. The most efficient way is `replacingOccurrences` with `regularExpression` option.

Declare the struct (once again the CodingKeys are not needed and name the struct members *camelCased*)

```
struct TableStructure: Decodable {
  let person: String
  let allowdate: Date
  let readyTime: String
}
```

and add the strategy

```
do {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
    decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .custom({ decoder -> Date in
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        let dateString = try container.decode(String.self)
        let trimmedString = dateString.replacingOccurrences(of: "(st|nd|rd|th) ", with: " ", options: .regularExpression)
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
        formatter.dateFormat = "MMMM dd yyyy"
        guard let result = formatter.date(from: trimmedString) else { throw DecodingError.dataCorruptedError(in: container, debugDescription: "Wrong date format")}
        return result
    })
    self.structure.sort { $1. allowdate < $0.allowdate }
    let res = try decoder.decode([TableStructure].self, from: data)
    let grouped = Dictionary(grouping: res, by: { $0. allowdate })
    let keys = grouped.keys.sorted()
    self.sections = keys.map({TableSection(date: $0, items: grouped[$0]!)})
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }

}
```

Consider that a `Date` is printed with a default date format. If you need a custom date format you have to add a second date formatter